# CSS @print rules not breaking pages automatically on dynamic lengthy content

Tags: html, css, angular8, page-break, css-paged-media

I'm trying to print a `div` which can be very lengthy after adding dynamic content inside, & I have currently declared CSS `@print` query properties to print only this div in my html on a A4 length paper,

It works fine & works very well when the content length is shorter than the length of an A4 page, But as soon as the content gets longer than A4 length, the printable version still shows one page, & it only captures the content which can be fitted inside the A4 page **only**, other below lot is being clipped.

I want to break the page automatically when the content hits the bottom of the page. 
I tried for hours, googling & testing. (Chrome/Firefox/Opera all shows the same result)

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 4.4in 11.69in;
    /* custom width which I use for printing */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /* app-home is the parent component */
  app-root app-home>* {
    display: none !important;
    /*As I want to print only the div which is mentioned below */
  }
  
  /* app-preview component which holds the div to be printed */
  app-root app-home app-preview,
  app-root app-home app-preview>* {
    display: block !important;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible !important;
    break-inside: auto !important;
    break-after: auto !important;
  }
  
  /* div with class of canvas - The div to be printed */
  /* div with class of outer is a parent div */
  app-root app-home app-preview div.outer div.canvas {
    display: block !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    break-inside: auto !important;
    break-after: auto !important;
  }
}
```

Note: **The content `div` is inside of a component of an Angular 8 application**.
 + the actual content is in a `table` inside this `div`.
The styles mentioned are in main `styles.css` file.

The print preview as shown in Chrome - [image: Print preview in Chrome]

The rest is clipped & not broke on to another page, as it should.
Any idea on what is wrong with my code?

Any help would be appreciated!